# How do I change and translate the "completion message" in Commerce checkouts?

Tags: 8, commerce

I want to change the text of the "completion message" that is shown when an order is paid for successfully.  I also want to translate this message.

By default, the completion message text is:

```
Your order number is 1. 
You can view your order on your account page when logged in.
```

I'm using Commerce 2 with Drupal 8.4.1.

By default, at `/admin/commerce/config/checkout-flows/manage/default`, the checkout flow looks like this:

[image: commerce_default_checkout_flow]

There is no option to edit the **completion message**.  Also, there is a **translate** link at the top of the page, but this **translate** link only lets me translate the name of the checkout flow, not the completion message.

So how do I edit/translate the completion message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Template approach (recommended)**

As revealed in the comment by @bojanz, you can just make a copy of the template file in your theme:

`commerce/modules/checkout/templates/commerce-checkout-completion-message.html.twig`

**Custom checkout pane approach**

There is [documentation for this](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/checkout/create-custom-checkout-pane).

You can create your own custom checkout pane, which can be done with drupal console or by hand.

`/MYMODULE/src/Plugin/Commerce/CheckoutPane`

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_checkout_pane\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane;

use Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\CheckoutPaneInterface;
use Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\CheckoutPaneBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * @CommerceCheckoutPane(
 *  id = "custom_completion_message",
 *  label = @Translation("Custom completion message"),
 *  admin_label = @Translation("Custom completion message"),
 * )
 */
class CustomCompletionMessage extends CheckoutPaneBase implements CheckoutPaneInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildPaneForm(array $pane_form, FormStateInterface $form_state, array &$complete_form) {
    $pane_form['message'] = [
      '#markup' => $this->t('This is a custom completion message.'),
    ];
    return $pane_form;
  }

}
```

Comment: You don't need to create a custom checkout pane.
The entire completion message is a Twig template that you can override:
https://github.com/drupalcommerce/commerce/blob/8.x-2.x/modules/checkout/templates/commerce-checkout-completion-message.html.twig

Comment: @BojanZivanovic Thanks, added to the answer so that people won't be guided to do something extra complicated.

Comment: @PatrickKenny I appreciate your answer, and also the custom checkout pane information. I'm going to try this. I would really love to see a detailed tutorial on implementing a custom commerce experience, including your custom module. I don't think the Drupal Commerce docs are detailed enough.

Comment: Thanks Bojan, this worked perfectly.

Comment: This is helpful, but I'm wondering why content is hard-coded in a template file. Could the content be sourced from the database and be configurable like it is elsewhere?

Comment: @imclean If you didn't want a template, you could code a custom checkout pane, as described in the answer, but that adds extra complexity...

Comment: @PatrickKenny that's my point I guess. I'm trying to find out why it was done this way. I'm not a fan of fiddling with template files or creating plugins just to change a bit of content. This could easily be configurable within the specific checkout flow.

Comment: Looking at a related issue, there was clearly a change in how this was handled between comment #5 and #8: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/2869452

Comment: This looks promising: https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/cobenash/3104732

Comment: While this answer is correct, we're now using the above module with some bug fixes: https://www.drupal.org/project/3104732/issues/3136056